# How to change date color in callander based on seat availability in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project where I want to change the colour of date based on seats available. I have 40 rooms in the states. if I have more 15 rooms available than it will be green, if rooms < "15" it will be yellow, if rooms = "0" it will be red and also it will automatically update seats after booking.

Comment: can you share a codesandbox with what you have done so far?